# In ASP.NET, how to make the aspx file accessible while the httphandler works

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, httphandler

I must admit that the demand is weird. I have an asp.net web project. In it, there is a web.config with a handlers node, as below:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="CServiceStack.Factory" type="MyOB.Mega" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

The path is '*' that means all the requests will be handled by the 'MyOB.Mega' module.
I want the aspx files can be visited normally, how to edit the web.config?

Comment: Which files should it handle?

Comment: ?  all the requests will be handled by the 'MyOB.Mega' module. So any files I think

Comment: What files do you WANT MyOB.Mega to handle, and why? Usually you just indicate a certain extension or path, but not the whole shebang. Can you specify a type of file that must be handled there?

Comment: I want MyOB.Mega to handle all the file types except 'aspx file', how to do it?